# Clamp Z rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

here is my quite simple code, basically rotating around a target on the x and y. but if i press both at the same time, it rotates on the z, flipping the camera. is there a way that i can lock the z axis?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Camera_Logic : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float rotateSpeed;

   public Transform rotateTarget;
   void Start()
   {

   }

   void Update()
   {
       float rotateAxisX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
       float rotateAxisY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

       transform.RotateAround(rotateTarget.transform.position, Vector3.up * -rotateAxisX, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
       transform.RotateAround(rotateTarget.transform.position, Vector3.right * rotateAxisY, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are rotating respect to the world axis, with `Vector3.up` and `Vector3.right`, you cannot lock local axis z. Its orientation moves inherently in the respect to world axis rotation.

I think that what you might need is to rotate respect the local axis of the object.
Instead of world axis `Vector3.up` and `Vector3.right` use the local object up and right respectively as follows:

```
void Update()
    {
        float rotateAxisX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float rotateAxisY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        transform.RotateAround(rotateTarget.transform.position, rotateTarget.up * -rotateAxisX, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.RotateAround(rotateTarget.transform.position, rotateTarget.right * rotateAxisY, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

This way you will rever rotate respect object's z axis. However z orientation will be changing also as the orientation respect one axis, involves the orientation change of the other two.